# Java NIO reading and writing from distant machine

Tags: java, networking, tcp, nio

I'd like to use the NIO to send/receive data to/from a distant machine.  I can send or receive data at any time, when i need to send data i just send it without any queries from the distant machine, and the distant machine send me data at regular interval.  I don't understand the NIO mechanism.  What generates and read or write event on the Selector SelectionKey ?  Is it possible to use only one ServerSocketChannel on my side, to read data from the distant machine et to write data to it ?  That is what i understand but i don't see how the writing event can be triggered...  Thank you for your explanation.

I already did some coding and i can read data coming in from the distant machine, but cannot write.  I use Selector and i don't know how can i write data.  The logged message "handle write" is never written, but in wireshark i can see my packet.

```
    public class ServerSelector {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServerSelector.class.getName());
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 3000; // Wait timeout (milliseconds)
    private static final int MAXTRIES = 3;
    private final Selector selector;

    public ServerSelector(Controller controller, int... servPorts) throws IOException {
        if (servPorts.length <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter(s) : <Port>...");
        }
        Handler consolehHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        consolehHandler.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        logger.addHandler(consolehHandler);

        // Create a selector to multiplex listening sockets and connections
        selector = Selector.open();

        // Create listening socket channel for each port and register selector
        for (int servPort : servPorts) {
            ServerSocketChannel listnChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            listnChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(servPort));

            listnChannel.configureBlocking(false); // must be nonblocking to register
            // Register selector with channel.  The returned key is ignored
            listnChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        }

        // Create a handler that will implement the protocol
        IOProtocol protocol = new IOProtocol();

        int tries = 0;
        // Run forever, processing available I/O operations
        while (tries < MAXTRIES) {
            // Wait for some channel to be ready (or timeout)
            if (selector.select(TIMEOUT) == 0) { // returns # of ready chans
                System.out.println(".");
                tries += 1;
                continue;
            }

            // Get iterator on set of keys with I/O to process
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIter = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keyIter.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keyIter.next(); // Key is a bit mask
                // Server socket channel has pending connection requests?
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "handle accept");
                    protocol.handleAccept(key, controller);
                }

                // Client socket channel has pending data?
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "handle read");
                    protocol.handleRead(key);
                }

                // Client socket channel is available for writing and
                // key is valid (i.e., channel not closed) ?
                if (key.isValid() && key.isWritable()) {
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "handle write");
                    protocol.handleWrite(key);
                }
                keyIter.remove(); // remove from set of selected keys
                tries = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The protocol

```
    public class IOProtocol implements Protocol {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IOProtocol.class.getName());

    IOProtocol() {
        Handler consolehHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        consolehHandler.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        logger.addHandler(consolehHandler);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param key
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Override
    public void handleAccept(SelectionKey key, Controller controller) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel clntChan = ((ServerSocketChannel) key.channel()).accept();
        clntChan.configureBlocking(false); // Must be nonblocking to register
        controller.setCommChannel(clntChan);
        // Register the selector with new channel for read and attach byte buffer
        SelectionKey socketKey = clntChan.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE, controller);
    }

    /**
     * Client socket channel has pending data
     *
     * @param key
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Override
    public void handleRead(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        Controller ctrller = (Controller)key.attachment();
        try {
            ctrller.readData();
        } catch (CommandUnknownException ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
    }

    /**
     * Channel is available for writing, and key is valid (i.e., client channel
     * not closed).
     *
     * @param key
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Override
    public void handleWrite(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {

        Controller ctrl = (Controller)key.attachment();
        ctrl.writePendingData();
        if (!buf.hasRemaining()) { // Buffer completely written ?
            // Nothing left, so no longer interested in writes
            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        }
    buf.compact();
    }
}
```

The controller

```
    /**
     * Fill buffer with data.
     * @param msg The data to be sent
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private void writeData(AbstractMsg msg) throws IOException {
//        
        writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(msg.getSize() + 4);
        writeBuffer.putInt(msg.getSize());
        msg.writeHeader(writeBuffer);
        msg.writeData(writeBuffer);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Write data - message size : {0}", new Object[]{msg.getSize()});
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Write data - message : {0}", new Object[]{msg});
    }

    /**
     * Write to the SocketChannel
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public void writePendingData() throws IOException {
        commChannel.write(writeBuffer);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServerSocketChannel` is used to make a connection, but not send data. You need one `ServerSocketChannel` and one `SocketChannel` per each connection.

Examples of reading and writing using `SocketChannel`:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
int bytesRead = socketChannel.read(buf);
```

Your program will sleep at second line until data will come. You need to put this code in infinite loop and run it in background `Thread`. When data came you can process it from this thread, then wait for another data to come.

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
buf.clear();
buf.put("Hello!".getBytes());

buf.flip();

while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
    channel.write(buf);
}
```

There is no blocking methods, so if you sending small byte buffer you can call this from your main `Thread`.

[Source](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/socket-channel.html)

**ADD:**
Don't set `OP_WRITE` key on new connection. Only `OP_READ`. When you want to write some data you need to notify selector that you want to send something and send it in events loop. Good solution is to make a `Queue` of outcoming messages. Then follow this steps:

- adding data to `Queue`
- setting `OP_WRITE` to channel's key
- in `while (keyIter.hasNext())` loop you'll have `writable key`, write all data from queue and remove `OP_WRITE` key.

It's hard for me to understand your code, but I think you'll find out what's the problem. Also if you want to have only one connection there is no need to use `Selector`. And this is weird that you binding few `ServerSocketChannels`.

Comment: These methods are all blocking unless you put the channel into non-blocking mode. It is not necessary to 'notify the selector that you want to send something'. There is no necessity for a Queue of outgoing messages. Too inaccurate. -1.

Comment: @EJP What is your solution? If I write to `SocketChannel` from non-event loop, method `write` will block until `selector.select()` return. I thought that the right way to send data is doing it on getting writable key.

Comment: When I said that method is non-blocking, I meant that there is no need to use another thread to write data, `write` method releases block quickly for small buffer when `read` can sleep for long period

Comment: @alaser No, `write()` will *not* "block until `select()` returns." I quote the Javadoc: "The selection operations synchronize on the selector itself, on the key set, and on the selected-key set, in that order". `write()` doesn't block on any of those things.

Comment: @EJP, I have met the same problem as alaster says, write() will be blocked if the program is blocking on read()

Comment: @alaster if do not use selector how could the program write and read from the same channel concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use blocking NIO (which is the default behaviour for SocketChannel)  You don't need to use a Selector but you can use one thread for reading and another for writing.

---

Based on your example.

```
private final ByteBuffer writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024*1024);

private void writeData(AbstractMsg msg) {
    writeBuffer.clear();
    writeBuffer.putInt(0); // set later
    msg.writeHeader(writeBuffer);
    msg.writeData(writeBuffer);
    writeBuffer.putInt(0, writeBuffer.position());

    writeBuffer.flip();
    while(writeBuffer.hasRemaining())
        commChannel.write(writeBuffer);
}
```

Comment: I posted some code, i read data coming in, but don't know how to write data to the distant machine.

Comment: I have added some code based on your example. BTW: It doesn't matter how distant the machine is. The code is the same whether the server or client in on the same machine or on the other side of the world.

Comment: the `write()` would be blocked until the `selector.select()` return

Answer (score 0):

> What generates and read or write event on the Selector SelectionKey?

OP_READ: presence of data or an EOS in the socket receive buffer.

OP_WRITE: room in the socket send buffer.

Comment: Ok, but it seems to be not possible to generate an event when i want to write on the socket. In the javadoc for Selector.selectedKeys it says that it throws exception if someone attempt to add element to the Set. How generate a writing event then ?

Comment: Ok I'm gonna use the SelectionKey from the handleAccept method, pass it to my controller, set its interestOps to OP_WRITE in the controller write method.  I think it's gonna work.

Comment: @jerome This is only necessary *after* you have had a zero-length write. For the most part, just call `write().` If you get a zero result and there is remaining data, *then* register `OP_WRITE`, queue the buffer, etc, and when you *don't* get a zero result you must *unregister* OP_WRITE, because it is almost always ready, see my answer. You only get the zero when your send buffer is full.